# Blinking thing everywhere in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have a problem with my Chrome

Wherever I click, I see the blinking thing that we have in every text editor
(what is the name...?).

[image]

What can I do...??

I tried to restart Chrome but it still there...

Same about the laptop.

Mac, Chrome latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to disable a setting called "Navigate pages with a text cursor" under the Accessibility settings.

`Chrome settings(3 dots) -> Advanced -> Accessibility`

Alternatively F7 should do the same to toggle it.

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/77878717?hl=en

Hope this helps!

Comment: you're are my hero...!!! THANKS :)

Comment: No a problem! Take care:)